# Clean up table that has orphaned records

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have to remove orphaned records in `Base Table`.

**Base Table**

```
id | raw_data | unit    
1  | 20 | kg    
2  | 30 | km    
3  | 10 | s    
4  | 10 | s    
5  | 20 | km/s
    6  | 70 | mpg
```

**Table A**

```
id | field_1 | field_2    
1  | 1 | 2
```

**Table B**

```
id | field_1 | field_2    
1  | 3 | 4
```

The `field_1` and `field_2` in both `Table A` and `Table B` are referring to `Base Table`'s primary key.

Since in `Base Table` record with id 5 and 6 is not referring from any table, this two are orphaned records, i want to remove it from database.

```
delete from base_table base
where not exists (select from table_a a where base.id = a.field_1
                    or base.id = a.field_2 ) 

                    and not exists (select from table_b b where base.id = b.field_1
                    or base.id = b.field_2)
```

The problem is this query runs forever if my `Base Table` has a lot of records (2.5 million). And i might have 10 tables like `Table A` or `Table B` that has data referring to `Base Table`.

How can i clean up orphaned records on `Base Table`?

Comment: is "base" missing before the 2nd `not exist` clause for your query ?

Comment: @Grace i re-edited my question, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just use `UNION` to get all ids of `field_1` and `field_2` of `table_a` and `table_b`, and use `NOT IN` to filter.

```
delete from base_table 
where id NOT IN(
    select distinct field_1 from table_a
    union
    select distinct field_2 from table_a
    union
    select distinct field_1 from table_b
    union
    select distinct field_2 from table_b
)
```

Comment: The use of `union` and `select distinct` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Your current query is logically correct, and is possibly already the best option.  You could consider indexing the A and B tables:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_A ON TableA (field_1, field_2);
CREATE INDEX idx_B ON TableB (field_1, field_2);
```

This might speed up the exists lookups in your current delete query, possibly making them dramatically faster.

Answer (score 0):

`or` is going to kill performance.  I would recommend writing the code as:

```
delete from base_table base
    where not exists (select 1
                      from table_a a
                      where base.id = a.field_1
                     ) and
           not exists (select 1
                      from table_a a
                      where base.id = a.field_2
                     ) and
           not exists (select 1
                       from table_b b
                       where base.id = b.field_1
                      ) and
           not exists (select 1
                       from table_b b
                       where base.id = b.field_2
                      ) ;
```

Then, you want the following indexes:

- `table_a(field_1)`
- `table_a(field_2)`
- `table_b(field_1)`
- `table_b(field_2)`

You can test the performance using a `select` query.